# How pass the JSON response of one URL and pass it into another JSON URL to fetch the result?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, api

I'm trying to access all "landscapePosterId" from this JSON URL [API](http://staging.connectingdotsinfotech.com:8080/firestixAPI_dev_2/api/v2/media/fetchAllMediaSlider). In the JSON response of the above URL:
"landscapePosterId" is the imageID. I want to pass it in the URL below at the end to fetch the Image Like 
http://staging.connectingdotsinfotech.com:8080/firestixAPI_dev_2/api/v1/files/download/
Example:- 
http://staging.connectingdotsinfotech.com:8080/firestixAPI_dev_2/api/v1/files/download/5de660b91b5f7b5d95559311, so how I can merge these two API and access the image
Here is my code o access "landscapePosterId"

```
import React from 'react';
import Axios from 'axios';
import "react-responsive-carousel/lib/styles/carousel.min.css"; // requires a loader
import { Carousel } from 'react-responsive-carousel';


class Slider extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            data: []
        }
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        const response = await Axios.get("http://staging.connectingdotsinfotech.com:8080/firestixAPI_dev_2/api/v2/media/fetchAllMediaSlider")
        .then((response) => {
            //console.log(response.data)
            this.setState({
                data: response.data
            })
        })
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        const response = await Axios.post("")
    }


    render() {
        return ( 
            <>
            <Carousel>
                <div>
                    {
                        this.state.data.map((item,index) => {
                            return (
                                <div key={index}>
                                    {item.landscapePosterId}
                                </div>
                            )
                        })
                    }
                </div>
            </Carousel>
            </>
        )
    }
}

export default Slider;
```

Comment: [axios.all](https://github.com/axios/axios#axiosalliterable) may help. Do you need to fetch these images now, or just store the image ids in state for use later to load/display them?

Comment: Can you let us know what you have tried so far? Because with this code it seems you don't know how to use html. But you can prove me wrong. No api will create the image tag for you. So inside of the div create an <img src="http://staging.connectingdotsinfotech.com:8080/firestixAPI_dev_2/api/v1/files/download/{item.landscapePosterId}"> and you are good to go

Comment: @DrewReese I want to access the image and show it onto the Carousel using that two API. Form the first API I want to access all "landscapePosterId" and add onto second API to fetch the result, after fetching result I want to show that image onto Carousel

Comment: @jPO I have explained all the thing in the description that  I want to access all "landscapePosterId" and add onto the second API to fetch the result, after fetching result I want to show that image onto Carouse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the first fetch you have all you need to construct the src urls for the images to feed to the carousel. Map the data you received and destructure `landscapePosterId` to construct the src url. *Here I also destructured `id` and `description` for react key and image alt text tag for accessibility*

```
render() {
  const { data } = this.state;
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Carousel>
        {data.map(({ description, id, landscapePosterId }) => (
          <img
            key={id}
            alt={description}
            src={`http://staging.connectingdotsinfotech.com:8080/firestixAPI_dev_2/api/v1/files/download/${landscapePosterId}`}
          />
        ))}
      </Carousel>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit carousel load images]